# Moving to a new fragment when pull to refresh is progress in one fragment, makes the two fragments overlap. Any idea how to fix?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments

I am on `fragment A` that has a `ListView`. I have implemented the `SwipeRefreshLayout` in `fragment A`. When pull to refresh is in progress, I try moving to a new `fragment B` on `listItemClick`, both the fragments Overlap. Any fix for this?

Comment: Pictures? Code?

Comment: Try adding white background color to root element